# EclipseLink: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit failed

Tags: java, orm, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

I have a REST API Application in Java where I'm using EclipseLink. everything was OK, but after the code commiting I get this error when I want to run my app in my local machine. The error is:

```
Exception Description: [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.PaymentGraph] uses a non-entity [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.Contract] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field contract].
```

This is my **Contract.class**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Contract")
public class Contract implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long ID;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "CONTRACT_DATE")
    private Date contractDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "INSURED_PERSON_ID")
    private InsuredPerson person;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CURRENCY_ID")
    private ReferenceData currency;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contract")
    private Set<PaymentGraph> paymentGraphs;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contract")
    private Set<Payment> payments;

    private Long franchise;
    private Long tariff;

    @Column(name = "COMMISSION_AMOUNT")
    private BigDecimal commissionAmount;

    @Column(name = "BROKER_COMMISSION")
    private BigDecimal brokerCommission;

    @Column(name = "IS_COMMISSION_OFFICIAL")
    private Boolean isCommissionOfficial;

    @Column(name = "COMMISSION_PAYMENT_TYPE")
    private String commissionPaymentType; 

    @Column(name = "COMMISSION_ACT")
    private String commissionAct;

    @Column(name = "IS_COMMISSION_PAID")
    private Boolean isCommissionPaid;

    private String note;
    private String type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONTRACT_COMPANY_ID")
    private ReferenceData company;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "INSURANCE_START")
    private Date insuranceStart;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "INSURANCE_END")
    private Date insuranceEnd;

    private BigDecimal amount;
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "START_DATE")
    private Date startDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "FINISH_DATE")
    private Date finishDate;

    private String policy;
    @Column(name = "INSURANCE_PRICE_AZN")
    private BigDecimal insurancePriceAZN;

    @Column(name = "PROFIT_SHEBEKE")
    private BigDecimal profitShebeke;
    private String curator;
```

and this is my **PaymentGraph.class**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PaymentGraph")
public class PaymentGraph implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long ID;

    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_PAID")
    private BigDecimal paymentPaid;

    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_REMAINING")
    private BigDecimal paymentRemaining;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONTRACT_ID")
    private Contract contract;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_PAID_DATE")
    private Date paymentPaidDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "START_DATE")
    private Date startDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "FINISH_DATE")
    private Date finishDate;

    @Column(name = "IS_PAID")
    private Boolean isPaid;
```

this is my **persistence.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="insurance" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>org.simberg.datastructures.entity.Contract</class>
    <class>org.simberg.datastructures.entity.InsuredPerson</class>
    <class>org.simberg.datastructures.entity.Payment</class>
    <class>org.simberg.datastructures.entity.PaymentGraph</class>
    <class>org.simberg.datastructures.entity.ReferenceData</class>
    <class>org.simberg.datastructures.entity.User</class>
    <class>org.simberg.datastructures.entity.Address</class>
    <properties>
      <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />-->
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
      <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/insurance?useSSL=false" />-->
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:/Users/danyalov/Development/Java/insuranceDB;create=true" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />

      <!-- EclipseLink should create the entity schema automatically -->
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and finally **Full Error Stack**:

```
6655 [main] ERROR org.simberg.datastructures.entity.ReferenceData - 
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6ce253f1
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [insurance] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.PaymentGraph] uses a non-entity [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.Contract] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field contract].
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6ce253f1
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [insurance] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.PaymentGraph] uses a non-entity [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.Contract] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field contract].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at org.simberg.configuration.EntityManagerConfigurator.getFactory(EntityManagerConfigurator.java:27)
    at org.simberg.datastructures.entity.ReferenceData.initDummyData(ReferenceData.java:130)
    at org.simberg.application.App.main(App.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [insurance] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.PaymentGraph] uses a non-entity [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.Contract] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field contract].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1950)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1941)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:96)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [insurance] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.PaymentGraph] uses a non-entity [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.Contract] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field contract].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:230)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.PaymentGraph] uses a non-entity [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.Contract] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field contract].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.nonEntityTargetInRelationship(ValidationException.java:1378)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.RelationshipAccessor.getReferenceDescriptor(RelationshipAccessor.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processForeignKeyRelationship(ObjectAccessor.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processOwningMappingKeys(ObjectAccessor.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ManyToOneAccessor.process(ManyToOneAccessor.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processOwningRelationshipAccessors(MetadataProject.java:1578)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage3(MetadataProject.java:1831)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1865)
    ... 13 more
Insurance Project Started...
6721 [main] ERROR org.simberg.datastructures.entity.ReferenceData - 
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6ce253f1
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [insurance] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.PaymentGraph] uses a non-entity [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.Contract] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field contract].
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6ce253f1
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [insurance] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.PaymentGraph] uses a non-entity [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.Contract] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field contract].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at org.simberg.configuration.EntityManagerConfigurator.getFactory(EntityManagerConfigurator.java:27)
    at org.simberg.datastructures.entity.ReferenceData.getAll(ReferenceData.java:45)
    at org.simberg.datastructures.entity.ReferenceData.init(ReferenceData.java:37)
    at org.simberg.application.App.main(App.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [insurance] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.PaymentGraph] uses a non-entity [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.Contract] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field contract].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1950)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1941)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:96)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [insurance] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.PaymentGraph] uses a non-entity [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.Contract] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field contract].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:230)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.PaymentGraph] uses a non-entity [class org.simberg.datastructures.entity.Contract] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field contract].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.nonEntityTargetInRelationship(ValidationException.java:1378)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.RelationshipAccessor.getReferenceDescriptor(RelationshipAccessor.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processForeignKeyRelationship(ObjectAccessor.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processOwningMappingKeys(ObjectAccessor.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ManyToOneAccessor.process(ManyToOneAccessor.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processOwningRelationshipAccessors(MetadataProject.java:1578)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage3(MetadataProject.java:1831)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1865)
    ... 14 more
6724 [main] INFO org.simberg.datastructures.entity.ReferenceData - Reference Data Loaded
6724 [main] INFO org.simberg.application.App - Insurance Project Started...
```

Comment: I don't know why, but after upgrading EclipseLink from 2.5 to 2.6.3 via maven, everything works fine now.

Comment: I would have guessed it was an issue with older classes being on the classpath when running outside of Eclipse. If it happens, check the classpath to be sure it only has what you expect on it.